# Angular velocity when the centre of rotation changes

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

If you swing and throw a baseball bat:
The swing imparts an angular velocity about the handle end of the bat $\omega_e$, giving an angular momentum: $L=I_e~\omega_e$.
When the bat flies it rotates about its centre of mass with an equal angular momentum $L=I_c~\omega_c$.
The moment of inertia about the end $I_e$ is greater than about the centre $I_c$. So angular velocity about the centre in flight $\omega_c$ is given by $$\omega_c={I_e \over I_c}\omega_e$$
But if we consider conservation of kinetic energy of rotation we have
$$K={1 \over 2} I_e~\omega^2_e={1 \over 2}I_c~\omega^2_c~~\text{and}~~\omega_c=\sqrt{I_e \over I_c}\omega_e$$
Which is the correct calculation for $\omega_c$?
How is angular momentum and kinetic energy conserved?

Comment: Is kinetic energy conserved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also consider the linear motion of the center of mass.  The total kinetic energy is $K_{lin}+K_{rot}$, which will be conserved so long as no external forces act on the system.  In your consideration of the motion of the bat prior to release, the motion of the center of mass is considered as fully rotating.  In your consideration of the motion of the bat after release, there is a constant in velocity linear motion of the center of mass of the bat *and* the motion of the bat about its center of mass.

EDIT: Just to be clear, you should consider prior to release that the center of mass also has some linear motion in whatever reference frame you've chosen.  Let's be very specific about a possible setup of your problem.  Suppose I'm swinging a bat that we approximate as a rod of mass $M$ and constant mass density of length $L$ by our arm of length $R$. And by swinging, I'm thinking about holding the bat out with my arm and rotating my entire body with frequency $\omega$.  Then at the moment of release, the linear momentum of the center of mass of the bat is $M(R+L/2)\omega$, the angular momentum of the center of mass of the bat (as measured about the center of the coordinate system, which I take to be myself) is $M(R+L/2)^2\omega$.  And the angular momentum of the bat about its center of mass is $I\omega$, where $I=ML^2/12$, because the bat makes 1 rotation about its center of mass for every rotation of my body. But the above quantities are exactly the same just prior to release as just after release; no force acts on the system, so there's no change in linear momentum and no torque, which means there's no change in angular momentum.  So the center of mass of the bat simply propagates forward with constant velocity $(R+L/2)\omega$, which gives the center of mass of the bat an angular momentum of $M(R+L/2)^2\omega$ as measured from the center of the coordinate system (as before).  And the bat continues to rotate about its center of mass with a frequency $\omega$.

Comment: Does this mean the linear velocity of the centre of mass changes before and after release?

Comment: It means that depending on how you consider the system, the book-keeping changes.  Prior to release, you're saying that all the motion of the bat is rotational about the pivot point of your hand.  After release, you're thinking of the motion as about the center of mass of the bat.  You've changed your point of reference, so the book-keeping changes.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So is the answer: the angular velocity will not change after release?

Comment: In the example I gave, yes: the angular velocity will not change after release.